# Usability testing mouse trails

Tags: usability

Is there a FREE software for Mouse movement recording that would display mouse trails/heat maps for a desktop testing environment i.e. (in a 50min testing session)? 
thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this even if this was offtopic to those who are still looking the answer is Mousetracker by johnFreeman and Whatpulse.